# What does the entries in Agency Matrix say?

Tags: matrices

Let $G$ be a graph with $5$ vertices $v_1,v_2,\dots,v_5$ and corresponding adjacency matrix

$$A = \pmatrix{ 0&1&1&1&1\\1&0&0&0&0\\1&0&0&0&0\\1&0&0&0&0\\1&0&0&0&0}$$

Compute $A^3$ and explain what the entries say about the $G$.

$$A^3 = \pmatrix{ 0&4&4&4&4\\4&0&0&0&0\\4&0&0&0&0\\4&0&0&0&0\\4&0&0&0&0}$$

Not really sure what this all 4s tell me about? Is it that there are 4 walks available of length 3 from $v_2$ to $v_1$?

Comment: It's called adjacency matrix (think of adjacent vertices).

Comment: You are right in your statement.

Comment: Thanks @Fimpellizieri for the edit. It looks clean now.

Comment: @NicolasFRANCOIS Sweet. btw is there any other pointers that i can mention ?

Comment: Well, you can notice that your interpretation is true for $A$ and use induction to show that it is similarly true for $A^n$, $n>1$.

Comment: Looks like a room with four adjacent rooms connected to the central one by a door, and no communications between them. Makes predictions easy.

Comment: BTW, Is there any article for the square of Adjancey matrix, gives walk of length 2.